# Clob reading in python using cx_oracle - not working

Tags: python, ssh, cx-oracle

I am trying to fetch a clob data from Oracle server and the connection is made through ssh tunnel.

When I tried to run the following code:

```
(id,clob) = cursor.fetchone()
    print('one fetched')
    clob_data = clob.read()
    print(clob_data)
```

the execution freezes

Can someone help me with what's wrong here because I have referred to cx_oracle docs and the example code is just the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that there is a round trip taking place that is not being handled properly by the cx_Oracle driver. Please create an issue here (https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/issues) with a few more details such as platform, Python version, Oracle database/client version, etc.

You can probably work around the issue, however, by simply returning the CLOBs as strings as can be seen in this sample: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/ReturnLobsAsStrings.py.